# Oracle Counters for Perfmon

Tags: monitoring, oracle, perfmon

How to install Oracle Counters for Windows Performance Monitor (and operfcfg.exe) on a separate machine (other than the machine where Oracle Database Server is installed) ?
The Oracle database version is 11g Release 2.

**edit 1 :** I installed the Counters (using Custom Install in Client Installer) and added the necessary values to registry with operfcfg.exe. Oracle services/Remote registry services are working on both machines. Inbound/Outbound Firewall rules on default port 1521 are created. I tested the connection : it's working (after configuring tnsnames.ora [client] and listners.ora [server]). But the problem is that the counters are not showing in perfmon, what the heck ?!

**edit 2 :** Which registry value I should watch in the Monitoring Machine ?

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES\ORACLE11\PERFORMANCE
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET\2.112.1.0\PerformanceCounters (0=Disabled, 4095=Activated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Oracle's *operfcfg* first but the counters weren't activated so I used a Microsoft tool ([EXCTRLST](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/03/05/two-minute-drill-disabled-performance-counters-and-exctrlst-exe.aspx)) instead for that matter to avoid changing the Windows register values manually with regedit.